# Efficient way to get family of subsets by its number in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I have an n-element set, and I want to consider families of its k-element subsets of fixed size s.
For example, if n = 3, k = 1, s = 2, we have these families:

```
{{1}, {2}}, {{1}, {3}}, {{2}, {3}}
```

In my problem n, k, s are not so small, e.g. s = n = 50, k = 20.

Let us say all such families are ordered lexicographically (or really in any clearly stated order). I want to have an efficient way to get a family by its number.

I thought of using itertools, but I am afraid it won't work with such big numbers. Possibly I need to implement something myself, but I have no clear understanding of how to do it. I have only a following idea: enumerate all k-element subsets of n-element set (there is an efficient algorithm to get i-th element by i). Then enumerate all s-element subsets of comb(n, k)-element set, using the same operation. Now we need to generate a number in range (0, comb(comb(n, k), s)) and turn it firstly to the number of s-element subset and then to a family of k-elements sets.

However, such approach looks a bit complicated. Maybe there is an easier one?

Comment: this *might* be better suited for [cs.se]. Borderline case.

Comment: I wanted to post it here, because I am actually more interested in implementation. Solution I have described looks feasible, but not very pythonic.

Comment: Are elements of one family disjunctive? E.g. n=4, k=2, s=2, is familiy {{1,2}, {2,3}} valid?

Comment: No, families are not disjunctive and your example is valid.

Comment: Than your observations are correct and I don't think there is easier approach :-/

Comment: Your problem is called unrank in combinatorial algorithms (see this book 1stworks.com/ref/RuskeyCombGen.pdf) However, your precise instance is not clear to me. Can you give a larger generic example.

Comment: are you asking about how to write code equivalent to `itertools.combinations(itertools.combinations(range(50), 20), 50)` that doesn't take forever to start producing results? as implemented, `itertools.combinations` evaluates its iterable argument in full before beginning computation, so you'd be looking for a version of `itertools.combinations` that doesn't eagerly evaluate its arguments